# Rastrear requisições AJAX em andamento

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Estou trabalhando em uma página onde tenho um botão atualizar, ao clicar nele é executado uma série de requisições AJAX para completar os dados disponíveis na tela (4 requisições para ser mais exato).

Caso o usuário clique no botão de atualizar, eu gostaria de **desabilitar o botão enquanto todas as requisições não voltarem**, pois caso o usuário clique no botão inúmeros vezes acaba gerando diversas requisições, o que ocasiona que o browser trave também (fiz esse teste).

Existe alguma maneira de verificar se a requisição ainda não finalizou pelo próprio jQuery? Até onde entendi só temos o `.done`, `.fail` e `.always` para utilizar, e somente com essas verificações não consigo realizar essa validação para habilitar/desabilitar o botão.

Não sei se faz alguma diferença, mas estou realizando as requisições com a estrutura

```
$.post({},function(){});
```

Por acaso vocês conhecem alguma solução que permita rastrear se a requisição ainda está em andamento ou isso não seria possível?

Comment: Conhece `beforeSend: function(){}`?  Daria pra colocar uma variável de controle nele... Cada requisição iria definir essa variável, e ao final, todas iriam executar uma função pra checar se as outras requisições já foram finalizadas. Se servir pra vc, posso formular uma resposta nesse sentido.

Comment: @LipESprY hmm, dei uma olhada nela, teria como utilizar na estrutura $.post ou somente $.ajax? Então, se eu conseguir realizar uma verificação se todas ainda não voltaram para dar "disabled" no meu button, serve sim!

Comment: Cara, dei uma olhada **superficial** na documentação do *jQuery* e, pelo visto, não tem. Mas tb não tem mt diferença do `$.post()` pro `$.ajax()`... Pode até mesmo fazer um *plugin* pra facilitar na reutilização do código... Se te interessar, posso formular uma resposta dando uma solução pro seu problema.

Comment: @LipESprY se puder eu aceito sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe alguma maneira de verificar se a requisição ainda não finalizou pelo próprio jQuery?

Uma forma simples seria adicionar uma variável de controle. Ao completar a requisição do *ajax*, definir um valor nessa variável. Fazer assim nas 4 requisições. Dessas forma, utilizar o *Promise* `.aways()` da requisição *ajax*.

> eu gostaria de desabilitar o botão enquanto todas as requisições não voltarem

Daí podemos fazer uma função para verificar se todas as requisições foram completadas. Caso sim, habilita novamente o botão...

> estou realizando as requisições com a estrutura `$.post({},function(){});`

Nesse caso, vou usar `$.ajax()`.

> Leitura recomendada: [SOen - `$.post()` vs `$.ajax()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12820103/5988245)

Teoria explicada, vamos ao código:

```js
        var requisicoes = 0;

        $(function(){
            $('#btnIniciar').on('click', function(){
                $(this).prop('disabled', true); // Desabilitei o botão!

                fazerRequisicoes(); // Chamei as requisições

            });
        });

        function fazerRequisicoes()
        {

            // Requisição #1
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://foo.bar.com.br/baz/1',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                // Tudo que vai passar via POST
                // Pode passar um form.serialize() também
                data: {
                    // Td que vai passar via post
                }
            })
            .done(function(ret){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com sucesso
                console.log('Requisição #1 finalizada com sucesso.');
            })
            .fail(function(erro){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com erro
                console.log('Requisição #1 finalizada com erro.');
            })
            .always(function(){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar
                // Seja com sucesso ou com erro
                // Como o nome sugere: sempre vai ser executado
                requisicoes++;
                console.log('Requisições terminadas: '+requisicoes);
                if (checaRequisicoes(4)) // Serão 4 requisições no total!
                    habilitaBtn();
            });

            // Requisição #2
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://foo.bar.com.br/baz/2',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                // Tudo que vai passar via POST
                // Pode passar um form.serialize() também
                data: {
                    // Td que vai passar via post
                }
            }).done(function(ret){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com sucesso
                console.log('Requisição #2 finalizada com sucesso.');
            }).fail(function(erro){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com erro
                console.log('Requisição #2 finalizada com erro.');
            }).always(function(){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar
                // Seja com sucesso ou com erro
                // Como o nome sugere: sempre vai ser executado
                requisicoes++;
                console.log('Requisições terminadas: '+requisicoes);
                if (checaRequisicoes(4)) // Serão 4 requisições no total!
                    habilitaBtn();
            });

            // Requisição #3
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://foo.bar.com.br/baz/3',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                // Tudo que vai passar via POST
                // Pode passar um form.serialize() também
                data: {
                    // Td que vai passar via post
                }
            }).done(function(ret){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com sucesso
                console.log('Requisição #3 finalizada com sucesso.');
            }).fail(function(erro){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com erro
                console.log('Requisição #3 finalizada com erro.');
            }).always(function(){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar
                // Seja com sucesso ou com erro
                // Como o nome sugere: sempre vai ser executado
                requisicoes++;
                console.log('Requisições terminadas: '+requisicoes);
                if (checaRequisicoes(4)) // Serão 4 requisições no total!
                    habilitaBtn();
            });

            // Requisição #4
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://foo.bar.com.br/baz/4',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                // Tudo que vai passar via POST
                // Pode passar um form.serialize() também
                data: {
                    // Td que vai passar via post
                }
            }).done(function(ret){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com sucesso
                console.log('Requisição #4 finalizada com sucesso.');
            }).fail(function(erro){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar com erro
                console.log('Requisição #4 finalizada com erro.');
            }).always(function(){
                // Tudo que acontece quando terminar
                // Seja com sucesso ou com erro
                // Como o nome sugere: sempre vai ser executado
                requisicoes++;
                console.log('Requisições terminadas: '+requisicoes);
                if (checaRequisicoes(4)) // Serão 4 requisições no total!
                    habilitaBtn();
            });
        }

        function checaRequisicoes(numRequisicoes)
        {
            if (requisicoes >= numRequisicoes)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        function habilitaBtn()
        {
            // Após tudo terminar, vai esperar 3 segundo pra habilitar o botão
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#btnIniciar').prop('disabled', false);
            }, 3000);
            requisicoes = 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto secreto</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" id="btnIniciar">Iniciar requisições ajax</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Fiz esse código ignorando qualquer boa prática de estética e dinâmica, de forma que fique claro para melhor entendimento.

Como comentei, pode criar um *plugi*n para as requisições do *ajax*, caso haja semelhança entre as suas requisições (não anexo à pergunta). O intuito aqui é mostrar uma simples forma de "**conferir**" se suas requisições foram completadas (com erro ou não) para re-habilitar o botão.

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel No final das contas nem usei `beforeSend`... Dessa forma pode fazer com o seu `$.post()`...

Comment: Cara, show! Essa estrutura é muito boa, muito obrigado.

Comment: O .always, é disparado logo no momento de chamada da função?

Comment: Não. O `always` é chamado logo após o `.done()`. Ou após o `.fail()`, caso haja algum erro... Teoricamente, ele é chamado SEMPRE depois da requisição.